# Re-encoding MP4 from HTTP source with MOOV atom at end is extremely slow

Tags: ffmpeg

I am re-encoding an mp4 using an HTTP resource as an input.

The input's MOOV atom is at the end of the file and the input is large enough that I want to avoid downloading the MP4 in advance, and ideally I'd like to avoid having to pre-process the input to move the moov atom to the start of the MP4.

FFMPEG is getting bogged down making 1000s of HTTP range requests of a few KBytes each while seeking for the MOOV atom (or at least I think it is). Is there a way to tweak FFMPEG's MOOV atom seeking behaviour so that it makes larger range requests from the HTTP source?

I've looked at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http, but didn't find much help.

Comment: Just download the whole file and process it locally?

Comment: Ffmpeg is open source, you can tweak anything you want to.